# Merge partially downloaded (via torrent) files

Tags: merge

I am downloading large files using uTorrent and I mistakenly cut and pasted the download folder into another drive.

I only realized my error after I had resumed the download and almost completed the download of the rest of the original file. uTorrent had already created a new folder and file with the same name.

How can I merge these two files please.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do partial merges because there may be parts of the information that is stored nowhere.

- Close uTorrent.
- Delete everything in the old destination (where uT created the new files)
- Since you moved the original partial files to a new location, make sure you have space,
- Open uT Add the .torrent to save so it saves to the new location you chose, where your old files have been moved.
- uT will automatically do a force-recheck and resume form the % it was at when interrupted.